# Using binary data from Mongo collection as image source

Tags: node.js, pug, node-mongodb-native

I have an express app, storing data in mongo, using Jade as the view engine. I have a simple route that gets the docs in a particular collection, each doc corresponding to a product. The image is base64 encoded. When I try and render as an image though it doesn't work

My route is

```
exports.index = function(req, res){
   mongo.getProducts(function(data) {
      res.render('consumer/index', {user: req.session.user, products: data});
   });
};
```

The function that calls is

```
exports.getProducts = function(callback) {

   Product.find().exec(function(err, products){
      return callback(products);
   });
};
```

and then my Jade file has the following code

```
each val in products
  img(src="data:image/png;base64,'+#{val.image.data}+'", alt='Image', style="width: 20px; height: 20px")
```

Looking at the doc directly in Mongo (via robomongo) I get this

[image]

[image]

I don't know what I'm missing, because in another file I use jQuery datatables to show the documents, and the same approach there correctly renders the image, here is a snippet of the datatables code

```
"aoColumns": [
          {"mData": "name"},
          {"mData": "price"},
          {"mData": "category"},
          {"mData": "description"},
          {"mData": "image.data", "mRender": function ( data, type, full ) {
            return '<img src="data:image/png;base64,'+data+'", style="width: 20px; height: 20px"></>'}},
          {"mData": "promoted"},
          {"mData": null}
        ]
```

Comment: Have you try to access to data using : val.image.data.$binary ?

Comment: Yes, it just says `val.image.data.$binary` is `undefined`

Comment: can you send me a sample of base64 string that is converted from buffer. I am not able to show image.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The problem is val.image.data doesn't provide a base64 string but a buffer. So, you have to convert it first. This is how I made it work:

```
Product.findById('559f6e08b090ca5c5ce6942b', function(err, result) {
    if (err) throw (err);

    var thumb = new Buffer(result.image.data).toString('base64');
    res.render('index', { title: 'Express', img: thumb});
});
```

Also, there's a small issue on your frontend jade code, it should be:

`img(src="data:image/jpeg;base64,#{img}")      //No + and ''`

Note: You could get away with this for small thumbnails or such but it is not the recommended approach due to a number of reasons (such as the 16MB limit). You are much better off using GridFS. More at http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/gridfs

Comment: Hello I try to do this in Typescript but I am not able to get any result.

       const imageString = Buffer.from(doc[9].images[0].toString()).toString("base64");



This shows string : 77+977+977+977+9ABBKRklGAAEBAQBIAEgAAO+/ve+/vRPvv71FeGlmAABNTQAqAAAACAAOAQAAAwAAAAEP77+9W++/vQEBAAMAAAABC++/vVvvv70BAgADAAAAAwAACO+/vQEOAAIAAAAEbWRlAAEPAA
IAAAAHAAAI77+9ARAAAgAAAAgAAAjvv70BEgADAAAAAQABAAABMQACAAAAEAAACO+/vQEyAAIAAAAUAAAI77+9AhMAAwAAAAEAAS1B77+9aQAEAAAAAQAACO+/ve+/ve+/vQABAAAACAAAE++/ve+/ve+/
vQABAAAACAAAE++/ve+/vRwABwAACAwAAADvv70AAAAAHO+/vQAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA